# HashSet Rest model trouble Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a User model. It is using in my Spring Security, and i have there some HashSet field, which contains roles of my Users. But now i try to set REST. And when i get User object in json format i get also some infinity loop because of this HashSet.

MyController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/{login}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRest(@PathVariable String login, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user",dao.findByLogin(login));
        return "rest";
    }
```

Little snippet:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "login" : "roman",
    "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
    "email" : "email",
    "enabled" : true,
    "userRole" : [ {
      "roleId" : 1,
      "user" : {
        "login" : "roman",
        "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
        "email" : "email",
        "enabled" : true,
        "userRole" : [ {
          "roleId" : 1,
          "user" : {
            "login" : "roman",
            "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
            "email" : "email",
            "enabled" : true,
            "userRole" : [ {
              "roleId" : 1,
              "user" : {
                "login" : "roman",
                "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
                "email" : "email",
                "enabled" : true,
                "userRole" : [ {
                  "roleId" : 1,
                  "user" : {
                    "login" : "roman",
                    "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
                    "email" : "email",
                    "enabled" : true,
                    "userRole" : [ {
                      "roleId" : 1,
                      "user" : {
                        "login" : "roman",
                        "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
                        "email" : "email",
                        "enabled" : true,
                        "userRole" : [ {
                          "roleId" : 1,
                          "user" : {
                            "login" : "roman",
                            "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
                            "email" : "email",
                            "enabled" : true,
                            "userRole" : [ {
                              "roleId" : 1,
                              "user" : {
                                "login" : "roman",
                                "password" : "$2a$10$04TVADrR6/SPLBjsK0N30.Jf5fNjBugSACeGv1S69dZALR7lSov0y",
                                "email" : "email",
                                "enabled" : true,
                                "userRole" : [ {
                                  "roleI ....
```

What i can do in this case ?

Comment: Do you really need the bi-directional relationship? Create a DTO for the objects and return that instead of your actual entity.

Comment: do you mean create another class User without any HashSet<UserRole> fields?

Comment: No a flattend structure without the circular reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotate the `user` property of the `UserRole` with:

```
@JsonBackReference
```

That instructs Jackson that it is a circular reference and not to be followed.

Comment: Thank you so I also had the same problem